# Openstack stack stuck in deletion

Tags: cloud, openstack, openstack-nova, heat, openstack-heat

Tried stack deletion but it is failed to delete the stack. And I have removed the some of testvm's manually before deleting the stack.

When I checked the test_resource it is in Delete failed status. So that the stack got struck in delete.

Could you please suggest me delete the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at all the components of the stack.  Take a look at the service logs for the failed stack deletion.

For example, if your stack has (or had) a Volume and an Instance, and there is disagreement between Nova and Cinder about the Volume's attachment status, then the Volume won't delete, and that causes the stack deletion to fail.

Comment: Volume and Instance deleted manually.